# automatically formatting code with prettier with onchange not working

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

i want to format the file with prettier whenever the file changes. So i run this command to achieve that

```
onchange '**/*.js' -- prettier --write {{changed}}
```

This works absolutely fine when run through terminal, listen file changes and formats it.

But when i add this command as npm script in package.json it and execute it with `npm run prettier-watch`

it starts listening to changes but it doesn't format code when file is changed.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pwa-svelte-rollup-template",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-p serve autobuild",
    "serve": "sirv public --dev",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "autobuild": "rollup -c -w",
    "clean": "rimraf public/bundle.*",
    "prettier-watch": "onchange '**/*.js' -- prettier --write {{changed}}"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^13.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "onchange": "^6.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "rollup": "^1.17.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.1",
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.4",
    "svelte": "^3.6.9",
    "svelte-preprocess-sass": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "useBuiltIns": "entry",
          "corejs": "3.0.0"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
    ],
    "sourceMaps": true
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not IE 11",
    "not < 0.2%"
  ],
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "standard"
    ],
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "serviceworker": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 8,
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
      },
      "sourceType": "module"
    }
  },
  "eslintIgnore": [
    ".cache",
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

please tell me if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: i m using windows 10

Comment: `NOTE: Windows users may need to use double quotes rather than single quotes. If used in an npm script, remember to escape the double quotes.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue.
Change your prettier-watch script to this `"onchange \"**/*.js\" -- prettier --write {{changed}}"`